# Bug in Firebug related to pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I have Firefox 28.0 and Firebug 1.12.8 and on this page:

http://www.alsacreations.com/xmedia/tuto/html5/meter-progress/demo3.html

I can't see the CSS for the `<progress>` element within the [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel).

Why isn't it shown?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a known bug that's covered in [issue 6461](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6461), which probably requires platform support for returning all pseudo-elements for an element as described in [bug 874227](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874227).

You can at least edit the related `progress::-moz-progress-bar` rule within the [*CSS* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel) until that bug is fixed.

Also please note that questions regarding bugs or features within Firebug should better be asked within the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/firebug).